# How can I solve this problem when I attempt to build the iputils on Linux Ubuntu 18: C library 'cap' not found?

Tags: c, build, shared-libraries, ping

I want to see how ping and ping6 work.  I found this repository:

```
https://github.com/iputils/iputils
```

and it indeed has the source code I an interested.  But every attempt to build results in this error:

```
C library 'cap' not found
```

I have searched for this library (libcap) on the internet without success.  It does NOT appear to be included with pcap, as installing these packages failed to solve the problem:

```
apt-get install sqlite3 libsqlite3-dev libpcap0.8-dev
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `libcap`, not `libpcap`. On Ubuntu, you probably need something like

```
# apt-get install libcap-dev
```

You'll also need `meson` and `xsltproc`.

Comment: Thanks, Kevin Boone, for the tip.  I figured I needed a package like cap or libcap; thanks for the reminder that package might be libcap-dev.  As I said originally, I looked a bit but could not find anything helpful.